# Access to the docker container inside the virtual machine through the host

Tags: docker, pgadmin, vmware-workstation

I have a PostgreSQL container inside vmware(which Debian is the OS).
I want to connect to PostgreSQL through pgAdmin in my host (windows 10)

I tried to get the IP address of container by using inspect flag but windows could't ping that address.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you've started the container with a published port

```bash
docker run -p 5432:5432 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d --name db postgres
```

and then you can access it through the VM's IP address

```bash
export PGHOST=10.20.30.40 # the VM's IP address
export PGPORT=5432        # the first `docker run -p` port number (5432 is the default)
psql mydb
```

The `docker inspect` IP address is useless in this configuration and many other common setups; never look it up.

Comment: Thanks BUT psql: error: connection to server at "192.168.1.5", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Is your VM running its own firewall that needs to be opened up?

Comment: No i have't firewall but i used nmap and it says that 5432 is closed !

Comment: it is fixed by switch to bridge connection